# Is there a way to change the width of the <Tab> tag in <Tabs>?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, tabs

I'm working on an app, where one of the pages has tabs. The first and last tabs must have a width less than the ones between. Is it possible to have different width of tabs in React Native?

Also, the empty tabs must not be viewable, so, the user must not be able to click them or swipe onto them. Is there a way to do that?

Also, on a side note - is it possible to use other clickable items on the page to navigate between tabs? So, for example, if I use `Icon` tag, arrow-left and arrow-right, is there a function, that can help me navigate between the tabs?

Changing the `tabStyle` width, and normal `style` width didn't help... Googling doesn't help either :\

No idea how to make the tabs 'unnavigatable'. Googled around - could not find anything.

I have the arrows, they are the reason for this whole problem (they are needed in the project ¯_(ツ)_/¯ ). But also, don't really know how to make them navigate between the tabs.

```
showTabs():
var dates = []; /*a list of dates*/
var headings = [];
    headings.push (
        <Tab 
            style={{
                width: 5, 
                borderWidth:0, 
                elevation: 0, 
                backgroundColor: '#f4f4f4'
            }} 
            heading={<Text></Text>}> /*empty tab*/
        </Tab>
    );

    dates.forEach( (date) => {
        headings.push (
            <Tab
                tabStyle={{backgroundColor:'#f4f4f4'}}
                textStyle={{color: '#6e6e6e'}}
                activeTabStyle={{
                    backgroundColor:'white', 
                    borderTopWidth: 5, 
                    borderColor: '#0a7acb', 
                    borderBottomRightRadius: 5, 
                    borderBottomLeftRadius: 5, 
                    borderTopRightRadius: 1, 
                    borderTopLeftRadius: 1, 
                    elevation: 1
                }}
                activeTextStyle={{color: '#6e6e6e', fontWeight: 'bold'}}
                heading={ moment(date).format("ddd DD MMM") }
                style={{
                    borderWidth:0, 
                    elevation: 3, 
                    backgroundColor: '#f4f4f4' 
                }}
            >
                {this.aFunction(usesDates))}
            </Tab>
        );
    });

    headings.push (
        <Tab 
            style={{
                width: 5, 
                borderWidth:0, 
                elevation: 0, 
                backgroundColor: '#f4f4f4'
            }} 
            heading={<Text></Text>}> /*empty tab*/
        </Tab>
    );

return(
<Tabs>
 {headings}
</Tabs>
)
```

Width should be smaller, but it is, in fact, the same as the rest of the tabs.

Empty tabs must not be viewable, but the user can still swipe left/right onto them.

Arrow `Icons` should be able to navigate between tabs, but they are useless at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The following isn't exactly the best solution to the problem posted above, but it worked for me:

This is more of a workaround, than an actual answer, but perhaps someone will find this useful:
Using negative `marginLeft` and `marginRight` in `tabContainerStyle` in the  tag did the job. I had 2 empty tabs, that I could afford to be squashed out halfway, since they were covered by other `absolutely` positioned elements

```
<Tabs tabContainerStyle={{marginLeft: -45, marginRight: -45}}>
    <Tab>{TabData1}</Tab>
    <Tab>{TabData2}</Tab>
    <Tab>{TabData3}</Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Also a workaround:
The empty tabs are still viewable, but due to the fact, that we load data for 3 days in that layout, we just made sure, that on swipe to the empty Tabs, new data for the previous/next 3 days would be displayed.

Actual answer:
To navigate to different tabs using other components (for example, arrow-left/right), you can add a `ref` to the  tag and call it by the following:
`this.refs.mytabs.goToPage(x)`, `x` being the index of the tab in the array.
This also solves the issue of data not loading on initial render in the first tab... So, setting a timeout in `ComponentDidMount` will make sure, that the screen navigates to the tab you want, and will load all the data on initial render.
[Link](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1318) to similar issue found on GitHub:

```
this.state={
    initialTabPage: 1
}

<Tabs ref={REFERENCE} tabContainerStyle={{marginLeft: -45, marginRight: -45}}>
    <Tab>{DayOneData}</Tab>
    <Tab>{DayTwoData}</Tab>
    <Tab>{DayThreeData}</Tab>
</Tabs>

ComponentDidMount(){
    this.gotToTab()
}

gotToTab(){
    setTimeout(()=> {
        this.refs.REFERENCE.goToPage(this.state.initialTabPage)
    }, 200);
}
```

Hope this will help some lost souls such as myself, and they won't need to waste hours of precious time :)